# Regex in Bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want to write a regex that will match `fooo-1234567890.csv` 
here is what I've tried:

```
if [[ $path == *.csv ]]; then if [[ $path =~ ^.*-\d{10}.csv$ ]]; then echo "COOL"; fi; fi;
```

But unfortunately it doesn't print "COOL".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` doesn't understand `\d`.  Say `[0-9]` instead.

```
[[ $path =~ ^.*-[0-9]{10}\.csv$ ]]
```

Moreover, escape the `.` in order to match a literal `.`.